# MYSQL error code:1805 password won't update

Tags: mysql, mysqlcommand

When mysql password expired.I tried to set it.But I get this following error while I'm reset password.

**ERROR:**`Failed! Error: Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 45, found 46. The table is probably corrupted`

How I can resolve this problem...

Comment: are you using phpmyadmin?

Comment: you need to run mysql_upgrade maybe. Which version?